# Error with Button findViewById()

Tags: java, android, button, io

i want to add a page to my app and it contains a button
but its facing this error

```
 /src/com/me/my/bk/BkFragment.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

at first it was 9 errors i solved them and now i have this error here is my code :

```
   package com.me.my.bk;

import com.me.my.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BkFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = BkFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public static BkFragment newInstance() {
        return new BkFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bk, container, false);
    }

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Process p=null;
                try {
                    p = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command("/sdcard/test.sh")
                    .start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(p!=null) p.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any solution for this error im facing ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: If any response help you, you should accept the answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. ;) I see that another questions that you made, you don't accept any answer, and maybe you are new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This code should work.

```
 private Button button;         
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bk, container, false);
    setViewRefs(view);
    return view;
}


private void setViewRefs(View view){
     button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do everything on the onCreateView not in onCreate

```
 View a = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bk, container, false);

 listView = (ListView) a.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: now i get this /home/nikan/DualBootPatcher/Android_GUI/src/com/github/chenxiaolong/dualbootpatcher/bk/BkFragment.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_bk);

Comment: I edit my answer, because I don't see that is a fragment